# share internet connection (via hotspot) with a lan with ieee 802.1X encryption

Tags: hot-spot, connection-sharing

my dorm internet is protected with IEEE 802.1X encryption (Microsoft PEAP) and I want to share the connection with my phone, but so far, I haven't been able to do it. I can create the hotspot, but the phone doesn't connect to the internet. Is there any way to share it?

It is not that I don't know how to create a hotspot, I've been using it at home during last year, but now, I've moved to a new home and to access the internet I need to configure a proxy and use my username and password for university and also it is protected with verification according to the standard IEEE 802.1x and Protocol PEAP, so even if I create the hotspot and connect to it, the phone/other computer/tablet/whatever can't go to internet.

I need something to tell the hotspot to go through the proxy and authentication, because I think that's the problem

These are the instructions for windows http://www.vscht-suz.cz/content/files/How_to_connect_en.pdf in case I couldn't make myself clear enough